executing mariadb-dump with password over ssh
I need to make backups of the remote machine mariadb database. My plan is to run
ssh user@remoteip 'mariadb-dump -uuser -ppass --all-databases' > backup.sql

from my local machine.
I found that remote machines history is not being populated with the mariadb-dump command I just executed. journalctl also did not contain the command.
Is there any security reason on the remote side I should be worried about when passing mariadb password in the ssh command? Are there better alternatives?

A command for remote host is passed over encrypted ssh connection so it isn't easily accessible for third parties unless you are a person of serious interest.

I've made some edits to your commandline but now I'm unsure if I was right. Do you want to create backup on the remote host or on the local one?

@Kondybas Thanks for stopping by. Would the approach above be production worthy? This is just the firs step, the next ones are scping the dump to local machine, importing the dump, and (this one I am not sure on how to do it yet), testing the success of the dump import.

You do not need to complicate things. First, create an ssh portforward from local host to remote one: ssh -L 3307:11.22.33.44:3306 user@remote_server where 11.22.33.44 - is an IP address of remote host. Now you have local port 3307 forwarded to the port 3306 on the remote server through the encrypted ssh connection. Having that you can simply do that on the local host: mariadb-dump -P 3307 -u ruser -prpass -A | mysql -P 3306 -u luser -plpass Here -P 3306 is redundant but added for clarity.

@Kondybas I admire the simplicity. Unfortunately, little more tweaking is needed. I got an error: mariadb-dump: Got error: 2002: "Received error packet before completion of TLS handshake. The authenticity of the following error cannot be verified: 1130 - Host 'REMOTEHOSTHERE' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server" when trying to connect. On remote machine, i've got ruser@127.0.0.1 and ruser@localhost.

Just needed to replace 3307:11.22.33.44:3306 with 3307:localhost:3306, to reflect the mysql user present. Now it works, thank you.
